# on('change',...) not firing up in jQuery 1.11.1

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to set a change listener on multiple checkboxes with dynamic IDs in jQuery 1.11.1. For an unknown reason tho, none of the things I tried works. The script is loaded and works successfully until I get to the point where I do this:

```
$("input[id^='item_']").each(function(index,element) {
    // This part works
    console.log("Foreach loop: " + element.id);

    $(element).change(function(){
        // This is the part that does not work
        alert('Change Happened');
    });
});
```

I spent last 2 hours googling around and testing different solutions. I tried to replace the '$(element)' with '$("#"+element.id)'. Then I tried other functions, like bind(), on() etc but none of them worked. My project is a perl application, with this html:

```
[% FOR item IN items %]
      [% id = 'item_' _ item.title %]
      <div class="choice-row">
           <input type="checkbox" id="[% id %]">
           <label for="[% id %]">Item</label>
      </div>
[% END %]
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Check your console for errors. Also, is this element added *after* the DOM has loaded? Are you sure the selector matches?

Comment: ^^ It looks a lot like you have a basic syntax error in that code (missing `});`). Also note that `change` doesn't fire until the control loses focus. Also note that v1.11.1 is fairly out of date. :-)

Comment: No error in console and the selector matches. Yes, I can get its ID and properties, its only the listeners that dont work.

Comment: Do your `id`s really have `_` in them? I don't do Perl, but that `_` in that expression doesn't look like it's a string literal (wouldn't it be in with `'item'` if it were?). Your selector is looking for IDs with `_` in them.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I corrected the code, that was my mistake, sorry. Due to consistency, I have to use this 1.11.1 version.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes it does :)

Comment: Problem must be somewhere else. The code works just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/1pzs3nsf/

Comment: @caramba Im trying to rewrite this to a pure javascript (no Jquery). Will see how it works.

Comment: As @caramba stated, the problem was somewhere else. I posted an answer to this problem, you can read it there. Thank you all for your time and help :)

Answer (score 1):

So what I did not notice is that the project uses a javascript library iCheck. Seems like this library overrides all the classic jQuery listeners and implements its own. The list of the listeners is here:

[iCheck Callbacks](http://icheck.fronteed.com/#callbacks)

And in my case the JS code should look like this:

```
$(element).on('ifChecked', function(event){
    alert('Change Happened');
});
```

As this project is not made by me, I did not realize they use such a thing. I hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score -1):

Why are you using loop here? Instead, you can **attach an event listener directly on all of the elements in the set** using

```
$("input[id^='item_']").on('change', function(){
    var id = this.id;
    console.log(id);
})
```

Comment: While this is true, it's not an answer to the question. If the OP's code doesn't work, this code won't work.

Comment: I think it is the right answer because it is working fine.

Comment: Again: If the OP's code doesn't work, this won't work. If this works, the OP's code works. This is not an answer to the question. Re-read the question, and the comments on the question.